# How to trigger appending an element if someone selects a particular option value in jquery or js

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jquery, I'm trying to create a new table heading if the user selects a particular option - in this case "other".  However, the code below doesn't do anything - any insights?  (New to JS/Jquery).

**Note:**  The select element is appended to template through jquery as well (if the user checks a box).

```
    <th>Did you graduate?</th>


</tr>
<tr id="college_info">

    <td><input class="id_checkbox" type="checkbox" id="college_grad" name="college_grad" value="yes">yes</input>
        </td>

</tr>   
<script>
    $( "#college_grad" ).one("click", function() {
        $( "#college_info" ).hide().append("<td><select id='college_degreeName'class='degree_name'><option value='bachelors'>Bachelors</option> <option class='id_otherOption' value='other'>Other</option></select></td>").show("slow");
    });

    $( "#college_degreeName").one("click", function() {
    if ( $( "#table_headings .college_degreeName" ).value =='other'){
    $( "#table_headings" ).append("<th id=other_degreeName'>Name of Degree/Certificate</th>");
    }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Note: you're missing a single quote within the `th`'s `id`.

Comment: Your problem is where you're trying to grab the value of your collection. .value will return undefined or error. Have you used a debugging tool such as firebug?

Answer (score 2):

Direct event handling do not work with dynamically added elements. You shoud use live or delegate event handling.

```
 $( "#table_headings").on("click","#college_degreeName", function() {
        if ( $(this).val() === 'other'){
        $( "#table_headings" ).append("<th id=other_degreeName'>Name of Degree/Certificate</th>");
        }
    });
```

Comment: these have been deprecated for a LOOOONG time now.  Please do not share deprecated functions with developers new to the language.

Comment: Because he did not mention the version of jquery. In case of latest jquery. We can use $.on .